# How bad can a tacnode be for a polynomially parametrized curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, rational-curves

Given a curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ that is parametrized by polynomials $ x(t), y(t)  \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, it is possible that for distinct $t_1$ and $t_2$, we have an intersection or crossing $(x(t_1), y(t_1)) = (x(t_2),y(t_2))$ and, moreover, that the first derivatives agree at those $t_1 = t_2$ values.  Such a point is called a *tacnode*.

If I bound the polynomial degrees of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ by $d_1$ and $d_2$ ($\in \mathbb{Z}$), can I say something about how many derivatives could agree on two different branches?  That is, what is a bound on the number of matching terms in the polynomial at the tacnode?

Here is a graph of

$x(t) = t + t^2 + t^3 + t^4$

$y(t) = 5 t - 9 t^2 - 23 t^3 - 9 t^4$,

where two branches have a common tangent at a crossing point (one branch in red and one in blue).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the derivatives up to order $m$ coincide at $t_1$ and $t_2$,
you have a system of $m+1$ equations. This system is linear and homogeneous with respect to
coefficients. There are $d+1$ coefficients, so the system has a non-trivial solution when $m<d$. If you write the condition that $d$ derivatives coincide,
you obtain only trivial solution (zero polynomial) as the rank of the matrix of
the system is $d+1$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be d1 + 1 + d2 + 1 coefficients?

Comment: Your notation $\{ x(t),y(t)\}\in C[t]$ is ambiguous and unclear. Do you have one or two polynomials? Perhaps you mean $x(t)\in R[t]$ and $y(t)\in R[t]$, as your example suggests?

Comment: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are two different polynomials in $t$. The ambiguous notation arose in an edit.